# Java program starts out fine but then results in a memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I am working on a project that tries to use a neural network to learn how to play a game of checkers. While training my network, I have to run simulations of many games (10000+ games). When checking the heap memory using Intellij's memory viewer, everything seems normal. Each CheckerGame object and the fields associated with it (CheckerPieces, GameBoard, etc.) seem to be eventually recycled by java's garbage collector. This means that once a checkers game has finished, the resources of the game is correctly disposed of.

After running the training program for a bit longer however, it seems that Java's garbage collector decides to stop recycling my game objects, and then I eventually get an OutOfMemoryError as the game objects pile up.
Here is an example of what I am talking about [image: memory leak].

There is obviously some memory leak but it makes no sense to me, as the program correctly recycles game resources most of the time.

EDIT: Code

```
public class CheckersGame  {
private GameBoard board;
private Player redPlayer;
private Player bluePlayer;

private boolean isBlueTurn;

private int winner = -2;
private int redGamesWon = 0;
private int blueGamesWon = 0;

private int turnNumber = 0;
private int blueTurnNumber = 0;

public boolean gameover = false;

public CheckersGame() {

}

public void initializeGame() {
    winner = -2;
    redGamesWon = 0;
    blueGamesWon = 0;
    turnNumber = 0;
    blueTurnNumber = 0;

    redPlayer = new RedPlayer();
    bluePlayer = new BluePlayer();
    board = new GameBoard(redPlayer, bluePlayer);
    redPlayer.setBoard(board);
    bluePlayer.setBoard(board);

    isBlueTurn = false;
    board.setUpGameBoard();
}

public void turn() {
    Random rng = new Random();
    try {
        LegalMove[] possibleMovesRed = redPlayer.getAllPossibleValidMoves();
        LegalMove[] possibleMovesBlue = bluePlayer.getAllPossibleValidMoves();

        if (turnNumber == 150) {
            winner = 0;
            System.out.println("Tie " + NeuralNet.testint + "/" + NeuralNet.otherint + " | " + blueTurnNumber);
            NeuralNet.testint = 0;
            NeuralNet.otherint = 0;
        }
        if (board.whoWon(possibleMovesBlue, possibleMovesRed) == redPlayer) {
            winner = -1;
            System.out.println("Red Won " + NeuralNet.testint + "/" + NeuralNet.otherint + " | " + blueTurnNumber);
            NeuralNet.testint = 0;
            NeuralNet.otherint = 0;
            redGamesWon++;
        } else if (board.whoWon(possibleMovesBlue, possibleMovesRed) == bluePlayer) {
            winner = 1;
            System.out.println("Blue Won " + NeuralNet.testint + "/" + NeuralNet.otherint + " | " + blueTurnNumber);
            NeuralNet.testint = 0;
            NeuralNet.otherint = 0;
            blueGamesWon++;
        } else {
            if (isBlueTurn) { //Blue turn (NN)
                LegalMove nextMove = NeuralNet.getMoveNN(bluePlayer.getNetwork(), bluePlayer.convertBoard(), possibleMovesBlue, bluePlayer);
                bluePlayer.movePiece(nextMove);
                isBlueTurn = false;
                blueTurnNumber++;
            } else { // Red's turn (random)

                int upperBound = possibleMovesRed.length;
                LegalMove randomMove = possibleMovesRed[(rng.nextInt(upperBound))];
                redPlayer.movePiece(randomMove); // executes random move
                isBlueTurn = true;
            }


            // gc
            for (LegalMove move : possibleMovesBlue) {
                move.clearTree();
            }

            for (LegalMove move : possibleMovesRed) {
                move.clearTree();
            }

            possibleMovesBlue = null;
            possibleMovesRed = null;
            turnNumber++;
        }
    } catch (InvalidMoveException ime) {
        ime.printCustomError();
    }
}
```

}

Training Code (scorePlayer gets constantly called and the results of the game is returned to the neural network ):

```
public class NeuralPlayerRandom {
private NEATNetwork network;
private static int playerIteration = 1;

public NeuralPlayerRandom(NEATNetwork network) {
    this.network = network;
}


public int scorePlayer() {
        int n = 0;
        System.out.println("Player Iteration: " + playerIteration);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.print("I: " + i + " ");
            n += this.doIteration();
        }
        playerIteration++;
        return n / 2;
    }
}

private int doIteration() {
        CheckersGame game = new CheckersGame();
        game.initializeGame();
        game.getBluePlayer().setNetwork(this.network);
      
        while (game.getWinner() == -2) {
            game.turn();
        }
        int winStatus = game.getWinner();
        game = null;

        return winStatus;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class LegalMove {
private GameBoardTile oldTile;
private GameBoardTile newTile;
private GameBoardTile jumpedTile;

private LegalMove moveBefore;
private LegalMove moveAfter;

private MoveDirections direction;

public LegalMove(GameBoardTile oldTile, GameBoardTile newTile, LegalMove moveBefore, LegalMove moveAfter, GameBoardTile jumpedTile, MoveDirections direction) {
    this.oldTile = oldTile;
    this.newTile = newTile;
    this.moveBefore = moveBefore;
    this.moveAfter = moveAfter;
    this.jumpedTile = jumpedTile;
    this.direction = direction;
}

public LegalMove(GameBoardTile oldTile, GameBoardTile newTile, LegalMove moveBefore, LegalMove moveAfter, MoveDirections direction) {
    this.oldTile = oldTile;
    this.newTile = newTile;
    this.moveBefore = moveBefore;
    this.moveAfter = moveAfter;
    this.direction = direction;
}

public ArrayList<GameBoardTile> getTotalJumpedTiles() {
    ArrayList<GameBoardTile> totalJumpedTiles = new ArrayList<>();

    LegalMove moveToCheck = this;
    while (moveToCheck != null) {
        totalJumpedTiles.add(moveToCheck.getJumpedTile());
        moveToCheck = moveToCheck.getMoveBefore();
    }

    return totalJumpedTiles;
}

public GameBoardTile getJumpedTile() {
    return jumpedTile;
}

public int returnNewY() {
    return newTile.returnY();
}

public int returnNewX() {
    return newTile.returnX();
}

public GameBoardTile getNewTile() {
    return newTile;
}

public GameBoardTile getOldTile() {
    return oldTile;
}

public void setMoveAfter(LegalMove moveAfter) {
    this.moveAfter = moveAfter;
}

public ArrayList<LegalMove> getPastMoves() {
    ArrayList<LegalMove> pastMoves = new ArrayList<>();
    LegalMove moveToCheck = moveBefore;
    while(moveToCheck != null) {
        pastMoves.add(moveToCheck);
        moveToCheck = moveToCheck.getMoveBefore();
    }

    Collections.reverse(pastMoves);
    pastMoves.add(this);
    return pastMoves;
}

public LegalMove getMoveBefore() {
    return moveBefore;
}

public LegalMove getMoveAfter() {
    return moveAfter;
}

public String toString() {
    if (oldTile != null)
        return "\nOld: " + oldTile + "\nNew: " + newTile + "\n";
    else
        return "\nOld: BEGINNING" + "\nNew: " + newTile + "\n";
}

// Returns the first that needs to be made in this move tree
public LegalMove getRootMove() {
    LegalMove moveToCheck = this;
    while(moveToCheck.getMoveBefore() != null) {
        moveToCheck = moveToCheck.getMoveBefore();
    }

    return moveToCheck;
}

// Captures all "jumped" pieces up to this legal move
// Returns ArrayList of pieces captured
public ArrayList<CheckerPiece> captureJumpedPieces() {
    ArrayList<CheckerPiece> jumpedPieces = new ArrayList<>();
    LegalMove moveToCheck = this;

    while (moveToCheck != null) {
        if (moveToCheck.getJumpedTile() != null) {
            jumpedPieces.add(moveToCheck.getJumpedTile().getCurrentPiece());
            moveToCheck.getJumpedTile().getCurrentPiece().capturePiece();

            moveToCheck = moveToCheck.getMoveBefore();
        } else {
            //System.out.println("Move " + this + " has no jumped pieces");
            moveToCheck = moveToCheck.getMoveBefore();
        }
    }

    return jumpedPieces;
}

public CheckerPiece getOldPiece() {
    return oldTile.getCurrentPiece();
}

public MoveDirections getDirection() {
    return direction;
}

public boolean equals(LegalMove move) {
    return (oldTile == move.oldTile && newTile == move.newTile && jumpedTile == move.jumpedTile && direction == move.getDirection());
}

public void clearTree() {
    LegalMove moveToCheck = moveBefore;

    while (moveToCheck != null) {
        LegalMove temp = moveToCheck;
        moveToCheck = moveToCheck.getMoveBefore();

        temp.moveAfter = null;
        temp.jumpedTile = null;
        temp.oldTile = null;
        temp.newTile = null;
        temp.moveAfter = null;
        temp = null;
    }
}
```

}

I left out lots of sections of the code and pieces that are irrelevant

Comment: How are we supposed to find a memory leak without any code?

Comment: That's no good, but we can not help you if you do not show code

Comment: Also for some reason, the memory leak occurs much faster on my linux laptop than on my windows desktop.

Comment: well the code does not show any `ArrayList` or the class `LegalMove`

Comment: There are no arraylists used because whilst trying to debug this problem, I switched most of the implementations of ArrayLists to arrays, I had been planning to do that anyways as it was more efficient

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
public ArrayList<GameBoardTile> getTotalJumpedTiles() {
    ArrayList<GameBoardTile> totalJumpedTiles = new ArrayList<>();

    LegalMove moveToCheck = this;
    while (moveToCheck != null) {
        totalJumpedTiles.add(moveToCheck.getJumpedTile());
        moveToCheck = moveToCheck.getMoveBefore();
    }

    return totalJumpedTiles;
}
```

I didn't go through the rest of the code to see what happens to this `ArrayList`, but if you keep creating new ones and never clean them up I can see where that would quickly become a leak.

Comment: or maybe as `LegalMove` objects are also seeming to be a problem, `public ArrayList<LegalMove> getPastMoves()`